# Remove specific duplicates from list with Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of objects in which I want to remove duplicates that have the same `id` and then keep the one that have `public: true`

```
recipes = [
       {'id': 1, 'public': True}, 
       {'id': 1, 'public': False}, 
       {'id': 2, 'public': False}, 
       {'id': 3, 'public': True},
       {'id': 3, 'public': False}
    ]

list_ = []
[list_.append(r) for r in recipes if r.id not in list_]

print(list_)
```

What would be the second condition to add?

Wanted result:

```
    recipes = [
       {'id': 1, public: True},  
       {'id': 2, public: False}, 
       {'id': 3, public: True},
    ]
```

Comment: `if r.id not in list and r['public']`   - BTW, don't use `list` as a variable. use `_list` or `l`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to do this with a for loop because you might want to add a `public:false` item and then remove it later when you get to the `public:true` version.

Comment: BTW, you can do `list = [ r for r ...` instead of, `list = []` and then `[list.append(...`

Comment: Are `true` and `false` booleans or strings?

Comment: @JacobIRR I also want recipes with r['public'] == false if they aren't duplicates. `if r.id not in list and r['public'] ` would remove all false.

Comment: You said you wanted `public: true` objects to stay. but in your wanted result, you also have a `public: false`. Forgive me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: @oldwooki booleans

Comment: @12944qwerty `public: true` duplicates to stay*

Comment: @Philx94 Ah, ok. That makes sense.

Comment: don't use a list comprehension for the side effect, that's bad practice

Comment: also don't use `id` as a dictionary value, you are shadowing the built-in `id`

Comment: What are the values of the variables `id`, `public`, `true` and `false`, and how is `'public'` supposed to become `public`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` to check if the entry is a duplicate.

```
recipes = [
   {'id': 1, 'public': True}, 
   {'id': 1, 'public': False}, 
   {'id': 2, 'public': False}, 
   {'id': 3, 'public': True},
   {'id': 3, 'public': False}
]

list = []
[list.append(r) for r in recipes if [i['id'] for i in recipes].count (r['id']) == 1 or r['public']]

return list
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient, building the `[i['id'] for i in recipes]` list and traversing it for the `count` call on every iteration of the outer list comprehension.

Comment: Also, it abuses list comprehensions for side effects.

Comment: True, but you can easily store ```[i['id'] for i in recipes]``` in a variable and it fits in the TO code without need for changing too much.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has O(n) time, hope it's enough:

```
ids={}  # Use a set to check for dups
l=[]    # Answer list
for i in recipes: # O(n) time
    if i['id'] in ids:
        if i['public']:
              ids[i['id']]=i
    else:
        ids[i['id']]=len(l)  # renumber the index for later O(1) use
                             # len(l) is a O(1) function, so no need to keep a counter
        l.append(i)
```

Sorry it's not a one-liner,but I think this is good practice :)

Answer (score -1):

You could first sort the list according to the `'public'` key, in reverse order, so that all the `'public': True` entries are on top. 
Then do a list comprehension to filter out unique `'id'` values sequentially:

```
recipes = [{'id': 1, 'public': True}, 
           {'id': 1, 'public': False}, 
           {'id': 2, 'public': False}, 
           {'id': 3, 'public': True},
           {'id': 3, 'public': False}]

recipes.sort(key = lambda r: r['public'], reverse=True)

recipes_unique = []
[recipes_unique.append(r) for r in recipes if 
    r['id'] not in [s['id'] for s in recipes_unique]]

display(recipes_unique)
```

This delivers the desired result (if necessary, you could of course sort by `'id'` again):

```
[{'id': 1, 'public': True},
 {'id': 3, 'public': True},
 {'id': 2, 'public': False}]
```